# Remote GUI Tools not available for Nano-Server

Tags: remote-access, windows-server-2016, windows-nano-server

I'm reviewing the new Windows Nano Server Installation option. I'm using the Server Technical Preview 2 and installed a Nano Server OS in a VM on a Server 2012 R2 Hyper-V host.

I can connect to the Nano-Server via PowerShell remoting and can do all kinds of things in the remote PowerShell session.

On a second Server 2016 with full GUI I opened Server Manager and connected to the Nano server, that works, but Computer Management is grayed out:

[image]

Is this by design?

Comment: I have exactly the same setup and the same greyed option but if you open Computer Management console and then select the nanoserver, some options are available although with some errors (for instance, the Services option can't show Description for some of the new services and shows an error message).

Comment: @PedroSousa - Thanks I can confirm that. Please add your comment as an answer an blame the greyed-out items on the beta status, then I can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is just a glitch in the pre-release. It is possible to open the `Computer Management` mmc snapin and the connect to the Nano Server from there.

In Server Manager is also reports for the Nano Server:

> Online - Windows PowerShell not installed

which is not correct.

I expect the remote manageability of Nano Server will improve before RTM.